# Override inline styles with !important properties?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, inline-styles

***ETA: (See bottom for additional info)***

Working with a very poorly designed CMS/cart system that has inline-styles embedded everywhere, and I am able to mostly override things using CSS, but there are some things left with hard coded `!important` properties.

It's not my favorite method, but fortunately I can use JavaScript and `.removeAttr()` to clean up the mess.  However, I am unable to get down into some deeply nested divs/spans.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#cartDiv').removeAttr('style');
});
```

The above works perfectly to remove all inline styles from `#cartDiv` but nothing below that is removed.  I tried adding multiple lines, and even specifically target everything from #cartDiv using targeted selectors, but it didn't seem to work.  I want to remove styles from #cartDiv AND all child elements below it.

Edit to add - Here is an exmaple of some of the existing code:

```html
<div id="cartDiv" style="top: 0; right: 0; width: 180px; text-align: center; padding: 0 5px 5px; z-index: 10;">
    <div style="display:table; height:28px; text-align:right; width:100%;"> 
        <span style="vertical-align:middle; display:table-cell; color: #ccc; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px !important;"> 
            <a href="javascript:ProceedToCheckout('no');" style="color: #fff !important; text-decoration:underline !important; font-family: Arial !important; font-size: 12px !important; font-weight: normal !important;">Check Out</a> &nbsp; | &nbsp; <a href="checkout/cart.php?1" style="color: #fff !important; text-decoration:underline !important; font-family: Arial !important; font-size: 12px !important; font-weight: normal !important;">View Cart</a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </span> 
        <span style="vertical-align:middle; display:table-cell; color: #ccc; font-family: Arial; font-size: 12px !important;"> <a href="#" onclick="ExpandCart();"><img border="0" width="16" height="11" src="https://siteimages.s3.amazonaws.com/btn-expand.png"></a> </span>
    </div>  
</div>
```

---

ETA (additional info)

So it seems that the !important styles are added BY the javascript (cart.js) file dynamically to the #cartDiv and this file is linked in the footer.  As I am unable to A, change the contents of the file; or B, change the contents of the footer (to maybe point to my own cart.js), I am left with trying to figure out how to override the following JS.

```js
// Cart - This is what renders the expanded version of the cart in the upper corner
/** @return {boolean} */
function ExpandCart() {
    var oldCart = window.cartVersion != 2017;
    var cartDiv = $("#cartDiv");
    var cartDivMobile = $("#cartDivMobile");

    var products = '';
    var subtotal = 0;
    var subtotal_to_discount = 0;
    var giftCardSubtotal = 0;
    var totalItems = 0;
    var numProducts = 0;
    var numGiftCards = 0;

    if (oldCart) {
        UpdateCouponsInCartArrayAndCookie();
    }

    // Item totals
    for (var i = window.cartArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var row = window.cartArray[i];
        if (row[0] == 'product') {
            if (row[1].indexOf('PITEM') > -1) {
                continue;
            }
            totalItems += Number(row[4]);
            var displayPrice = 0;
            if (row[25]) {
                displayPrice = row[25];
            } else {
                displayPrice = row[3];
            }

            var amount = Math.round((parseFloat(displayPrice) * row[4]) * 100) / 100;
            if (row.length > 16 && row[16] == 'GC') {
                giftCardSubtotal += amount;
                numGiftCards++;
            } else {
                numProducts++;
                subtotal += amount;

                // 19 - discount_eligible
                if (row[19] === "true") {
                    subtotal_to_discount += amount;
                }
            }

            if (oldCart) {

                products +=
                    '<div style="font-size: 12px !important; line-height: 20px; border-bottom: 1px solid #999; padding-bottom:5px; margin-bottom: 10px;">' +
                    '<div style="line-height: 14px; font-size: 11px !important; margin-bottom:4px;">' +
                    window.cartArray[i][2].replace(/\+/g, ' ') +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div><b>' + formatCurrency(displayPrice) + '</b></div>' +

                    '<span style="font-size: 10px; color: #999;">quantity: ' + row[4] + '</span><br><br>' +
                    '</div>';
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a recursive function, and I probably will. But in the mean time you could always:

UPDATE: added the logic inside a MutationObserver callback

```js
// original solution
$("#cartDiv, #cartDiv *").attr("style", null);


// recursive solution
function cleanStyle(elem) {
  elem.removeAttribute("style");
  [...elem.children].forEach(cleanStyle);
}
// cleanStyle(document.querySelector("#cartDiv"))

var cartDiv = document.querySelector("#cartDiv")


function addToCart() {
  var html = `<h1 style="background:blue !important">hello h1</h1>
  <div>
    <h2 style="color: red !important">?</h2>
    <h2 style="color: red !important">?</h2>
  </div>
  `;
  cartDiv.innerHTML = html;
}


const config = {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutationList, observer) {
  cleanStyle(cartDiv)
  // observer.disconnect();
});

observer.observe(cartDiv, config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cartDiv" style="padding:10px !important">
  <p>
  this is the empty cart
  </p>
  <!-- 
  <h1 style="background:blue !important">hello h1</h1>
  <div>
    <h2 style="color: red !important">?</h2>
    <h2 style="color: red !important">?</h2>
  </div>
  -->
</div>

<button onclick="addToCart()">add something COLORFUL to cart</button>
```

Comment: Bonus for very clean looking code, but for some reason that doesn't do anything for any child elements of #cartDiv.  I will however modify my question with a few more details.

Comment: it should work. make sure it's not re-styled using some other javascript. anyway you now have 2 possible solutions

Comment: Thank you, have to run some errands but will dive into this later this evening.

Comment: I figured out why it's not working for me.  jQuery linked to this system is still 1.6.2 ...   I'm going to see if I can get around that somehow.

Comment: So it doesn't seem to matter that it's using old JS.  I tested your code above with various releases and it all seemed to work, including the ones embedded into this site.  What I find odd is that using your code above, ``#cartDiv`` works, but ``#cartDiv *``  does not, nor does anything else it seems.

Comment: It's possible that the #cardDiv is getting its content (items and menu) dynamically, after the page loads. So when you try to remove the styles they're not even there yet.  If that is the case then maybe a `MutationObserver` might tell you **when** to strip the styles.

Comment: It's definately being added dynamically, after page load.  My limited dev skills I'm not sure how to use what you suggested.  Can I PM you a quick request to look at the page to see if you can figure it out?  I do have a live dev page I just didn't want to link here.

Comment: I think it would be best if I answer here after you first create a [mre] of: 1. initialize carousel manually. 2. use MutationObserver for observing changes to an element or its children.

Comment: While I'm trying to figure out MutationObserver I added more info to my original post (car.jts).

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically remove all style attributes from an element and all of its children and their children you can use the javascript `querySelectorAll` method with some css selectors. Here is an example using JavaScript rather than jQuery.

```
document.querySelectorAll('#cartDiv, #cartDiv *')
  .forEach((element) => element.removeAttribute('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the quick fix you're looking for however i've dealt with this before and in the long run the best thing to do is migrate/refactor styling into a scss file or _files.
For example changing something like this first h1 to the h2 and scss file

```
<h1 style='color:red !important'> this is bad> </h1> 

(change to ->) 
<div className='text-wrapper">
   <h2> this is good </h2>
</div>

SCSS FILE: 
.text-wrapper{
    h2{
        color: blue; 
        //could also add classname to the h2 html instead
    }
}
```